# Angularjs: ng-options: How to order options with group and non-group

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have my group by ng-options looks like this

```
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="d.title group by d.group for d in data"></select>
```

Here is my data

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        group:"",
        title:"No GroupA"
    },
    {
        group:"Group_1",
        title:"1"
    },
    {
        group:"",
        title:"No GroupB"
    },
    {
        group:"Group_2",
        title:"2"
    },
    {
        group:"",
        title:"No GroupC"
    }
];
```

the problem is that this creates the optgroup on the bottoms of this select menu, not the order as same as my data list.

```
No GroupA
No GroupB
No GroupC
[Group_1]
 1
[Group_2]
 2
```

i want to produce:

```
No GroupA
[Group_1]
 1
No GroupB
[Group_2]
 2
No GroupC
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59pxjzvs/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: thank you, @denisazevedo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't have a mixed select - options within and without groups.

You could create a generic group for these options:

```
<select ng-model="selected" 
        ng-options="d.title group by (d.group ==='' ? 'No_Group' : d.group) for d in data">
</select>
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59pxjzvs/2/).