# Is it possible to mix elements in ng-options with and without groups?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Until angular 1.4.4 (or possibly a bit further) it was possible to use groups in ng-options in a way that if the group name was an empty string or null/undefined, it created an option outside groups. Is there any way to do this in the new version 1.5.7? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644164/angularjs-ng-options-how-to-order-options-with-group-and-non-group), the accepted answer suggests adding a new group to collect all the non-group elements, but that doesn't suit my specifications. I certainly need an option at the beginning that doesn't belong to a group, and after that the elements within groups, which still works fine after migrating to the new version.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59pxjzvs/2/) for the linked question, where I want to get rid of the group that is named No_Group in that example.

```
ng-options="d.title group by (d.group ==='' ? 'No_Group' : d.group) for d in data"

$scope.data = [
        {
            group:"",
            title:"No GroupA"
        },
        {
            group:"Group_1",
            title:"1"
        },
        {
            group:"",
            title:"No GroupB"
        },
        {
            group:"Group_2",
            title:"2"
        },
        {
            group:"",
            title:"No GroupC"
        }
]
```

Comment: you can use only (d.group ==='' ? '' : d.group) instead of (d.group ==='' ? 'No_Group' : d.group).

Comment: y dont you remove the values from the arry before using ng-options

Comment: As I said, with an empty string it creates null groups, so it literally says *null* as the name of the group, that's what I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: thats wht i am saying if the gropu is null y dont use remove that before then use in ng-options

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your sentences

Comment: will it http://jsfiddle.net/bpx6vthj/ work for you.

Comment: @Viplock that's how I want it to appear, but it doesn't work with this code anymore after angular 1.5. The example fiddle is old, so it has v1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I need to feed *undefined* as the group, empty string or null doesn't work anymore. One option is to write the html part as follows:

```
ng-options="d.title group by (d.group ? d.group : undefined) for d in data"
```

But since I know which objects will be outside the group, I resolve the issue more elegantly by not adding them the group object at all, which would correspond to the following in this example code:

```
$scope.data = [
        {
            title:"No GroupA"
        },
        {
            group:"Group_1",
            title:"1"
        },
        {
            title:"No GroupB"
        },
        {
            group:"Group_2",
            title:"2"
        },
        {
            title:"No GroupC"
        }
]
```

Check out the [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/85e392f3543ef5285c7e90e843af0ab522cb0531) responsible for this behavior.